# Generalisation of Binomial Coefficient (Combinatorics on words)

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinatorics-on-words

So, when trying to find subwords from a bigger word:

$\binom{abracadabra}{ab} = 5$

with $ABracadabra$, $AbracadaBra$, $abrAcadaBra$, $abracAdaBra$, $abracadABra$.

I have noticed that it doesn't go back (like first $a$ then $b$ in $abracadaBrA$) and it looks like it iterates through all (factorial?).

I thought of cardinalitates $n\cdot a\cdot (m \cdot b - 1)$, where $n$ is the number of $a$'s and $m$ of $b$'s but it isn't that.

Also just for $\binom{a^n}{a^m}$ the binomial $\binom{n}{m}$ fits perfectly.

And what is the general formula about that one here?

$\binom{(ba)^n}{(ba)^m}$

Comment: If there is a question here, I can't find it. What are you talking about?

Comment: Could you put your question in words?  It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: @GerryMyerson is it better now?

Comment: But what is strange about there being $5$ occurrences of "ab" as a subword of "abracadabra"?

Comment: No. "I have this strange property" --- I don't see where you have stated any property, strange or otherwise. I don't know what you mean by "factorial?" In the formula, $\|na\|\|nb-1\|$, I don't know what $n$ stands for, I don't know what $a$ stands for, I don't know what $b$ stands for, and I don't know what $\|$ stands for. And I don't know what it is that you are trying to find a general formula for.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  what I am trying is to find is the number of subwords in a given word. And that would be some generalization of the binomial coefficients. That`s all.

Comment: Then maybe you should say that that's what you're trying to do, and leave out all the stuff that doesn't make any sense. But if you're going to allow arbitrary (finite) words and subwords, I doubt you're going to get any useful formula.

Comment: you can take a look at this http://static-content.springer.com/lookinside/chp%3A10.1007%2F978-3-642-40579-2_23/001.png but i still don`t get $\binom{ua}{vb} = \binom{u}{vb} + \delta_{a,b}\binom{u}{v}$ as they are defined in the link.

Comment: I think there is some discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877249/find-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-subsequence-in-a-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I recommend you to read [Chapter 6](http://books.google.fr/books?id=eATLTZzwW-sC&pg=PA105&hl=fr&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false) of Lothaire's book [Combinatorics on words](http://ebooks.cambridge.org/ebook.jsf?bid=CBO9780511566097).
The binomial coefficients can be computed from the three following formulas, where $u$ and $v$ are words, $a$ and $b$ are letters and $1$ is the empty word.

> 1. $\binom{u}{1} = 1$,
> 2. $\binom{u}{v} = 0$ if $|u| \leqslant |v|$ and $u \neq v$,
> 3. $\binom{ua}{vb} = \binom{u}{vb} + \delta_{a,b} \binom{u}{v}$

**Hint to prove 3**. If $a \not= b$, every subsequence of $ua$ equal to $vb$ is also a subsequence of $u$. If $a = b$, there are two categories of subsequences of $ua$ that are equal to $va$: those containing the last $a$ and those that are subsequences of $u$.

Another very useful formula is the following
$$
\binom{u_1u_2}{v} = \sum_{v_1v_2 = v}\binom{u_1}{v_1}\binom{u_2}{v_2}
$$

Apparently, you were looking for a formula to compute $\binom{u}{ab}$.
If $u = a^{n_0}ba^{n_1}b \dotsm a^{n_{k-1}}ba^{n_k}$, then
$$
  \binom{u}{ab} = \binom{a^{n_0}ba^{n_1}b \dotsm a^{n_{k-1}}ba^{n_k}}{ab} = 
n_0 + (n_0 + n_1) + \dotsm + (n_0 + n_1 + \dotsm + n_{k-1})
$$
Finally, if I am not wrong,
$$
  \binom{(ab)^n}{(ab)^m} = \binom{n+m}{2m}
$$